# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x(\cos x+\sin x)}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I was solving the following integral:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x(\cos x+\sin x)}\mathrm{d}x $$
Using the identity $\sin x=\frac{\tan x}{\sec x}$, I simplified the integral in the following way:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\frac{\tan x}{\sec x}\left(\cos x+\frac{\tan x}{\sec x}\right)}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2 x}{\sqrt{\tan x}(1+\tan x)}\mathrm{d}x=2\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{\tan x})\Bigg|^{\pi/2}_0=\lim_{x\to \pi/2} 2\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{\tan x})=\pi $$
However, I'd like to see a different solution, because I feel there's a simpler one **maybe** using the symmetry of the integrand:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x(\cos x+\sin x)}\mathrm{d}x=2\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x(\cos x+\sin x)}\mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: What could be more simpler than finding a simple antiderivative for your integral? Quit while you are happy, ahead, and with the most efficient solution. Cheers.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for the comment. In fact, I'm not sure if there's a simpler solution, maybe it's just my gut feeling

Comment: The integral is equivalent to $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \sec x\sqrt{\sec(2x)}\,dx = \sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}[\cos x(1+\cos x)]^{-1/2}dx$, though I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: **Simpler** is a subjective term. What is simple for me may or may not be simple for you.

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad that's not always true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substitute $t=\sqrt{\tan x}-\sqrt{\cot x}$. Then
$$
dt =\frac{\sqrt{\cot x}+\sqrt{\tan x}}{2\sin x \cos x}dx,\>\>\>\>\> t^2+4=\frac{(\sin x + \cos x)^2}{\sin x \cos x}
$$
and
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x(\cos x+\sin x)}{d}x\\
=&\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}+\sqrt{\cot x}}{(\sin x +\cos x)^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2}{t^2+4}dt=\pi
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Use the substitution $t=\sqrt{\tan x}$. When we see $\sqrt{\tan x}$ in the integrand, this substitution will often rationalize the integrand for us.
$$u^2=\tan x, \space dx=\frac{2u\space du}{1+u^4}$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x (\cos x +\sin x)}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{u^4+1}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^4+1}}+\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{u^4+1}})}\frac{2u\space du}{1+u^4}=\int_0^\infty\frac{2du}{1+u^2}=\pi$$
We can also find the indefinite integral. Using properties of arctan, we can find another substitution that works for fun
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x (\cos x +\sin x)}dx=2\arctan (\sqrt{\tan x})+C=\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}}\right)+C$$
This is why $t=\sqrt{\cot x}-\sqrt{\tan x}$ is also fine